# ELASTIC update failed because bad type of another field

Tags: elasticsearch

We are having some issues updating elastic search documents because some of the fields have values the are incompatible with their type, even though does are not the fields we are trying to update.
To be more specific, the problem is with fields of type **date** that have **float** values.
Is there a way to bulk update/format all the fields that have values that are incompatible with their type? Or maybe a query to retrieve all the documents that have such values?
Please see attached reference error when trying to update a field that is not "updatedDate"

[The update query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huona.png)

[The original document values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdFDq.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaMtP.png)

Comment: just as a general piece of advice - it's a lot easier to help if you can post things like code and non-graphical errors as text rather than screenshots. it makes it easier to read, search and replicate to help you :) gist/pastebin/etc is handy for hosting this too

Comment: what does the mapping for the index look like?